# How/why is Yongnuo allowed to copy Canon?

Tags: yongnuo

How is Yongnuo allowed to copy Canon, and why does Canon allow it? Does Canon see a significant loss in sales to Yongnuo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about intellectual property laws and patents in the context of manufacturing and isn't about taking photos.

Comment: Which stack would be more appropriate?

Comment: @vandidant, check for stack, related to law and stack, related to business. Because your question contain two questions from different areas